Angles in javascript
Why aren't angles in js like the angles we've learnt about?
I'm trying to make spinner wheel in js, and noticed that using
    for(i<sides)  
    const angle = (360 / sides) * i;

isn't quite enough.
Why is that?
Later I found out that you have to do it like this
const sides = 3;
const angle = (i / sides) * (Math.PI * 2) - Math.PI / 2;                
const x = Math.cos(angle) * radius + startingX;



Maybe because angles are calculated in radiants instead of degrees. I am not sure about the exact purpose of your code though

Because trigonometric functions in JavaScript are expecting radian values (360 degrees is PI * 2 radian which is approximately 6.283).

"Why aren't angles in js like the angles we've learnt about?" - radians are taught in schools as well

I know but usually sin e cos take as arguments angles not radians you need to convert it α * (π/180)

@DK usually? Every language I'm familiar with (C, Python, JS, Go, Java) the cosine function takes it's argument in radians. Probably because the stdlib cosine function in C takes radians, but I'm no historian. What "usual" are you referring to?

Please remember to read the posting guidelines and then [edit] your post accordingly. There is nowhere near enough information in your description or code blocks to constitute something that actually describes the problem. And also remember to read the documentation for the language and functions you're using, which in this case means reading MDN. Every normal programming language uses radians for trigonometry functions, or makes you explicitly say you're using degrees instead.

So i solved it like this:
const sides = 3;
const angle = (i / sides) * (Math.PI * 2) - 
Math.PI / 2;                
const x = Math.cos(angle) * radius + startingX;

Math.cos e sin use radians as params not °
